# error in stack Operation on an array in push operation

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I was trying to implement stack operation and while doing push operation the value being entered is always 0.
If I enter any number the result in the array loaded is always 0.

```
//Stack Operation
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int stack[10];
int top=0;
void push()
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter the element you want to add");
    scanf("%d",& stack[top]);
    top++;
    printf("%d",stack[top]);
    printf("The element is added\n");
    for(i=0;i<top;i++) {
        printf("%d",stack[top]);
    }
}
int pop()
{
    top--;
    return(stack[top]);
}
void display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=top;i++);
    {
        printf("%d \t",stack[i]);
    }
}
void main()
{
    int ch;
    clrscr();
    label:
    printf("1---->Push\n");
    printf("2---->Pop\n");
    printf("3----->Display\n");
    printf("4-----> Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    if(ch==1) {
        clrscr();
        push();
        goto label;
    }
    if(ch==2) {

        int f;
        clrscr();
        f=pop();
        printf("Poped Element %d",f);
        goto label;
    }
    if(ch==3) {
        clrscr();
        display();
        goto label;
    }
    if(ch==4) { 
        exit(0);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want the increament in between `scanf("%d",& stack[top]);
top++;
printf("%d",stack[top]);`

Comment: I think I got my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, your indexing is wrong. You may want to change

```
for(i=0;i<top;i++)
    {
    printf("%d",stack[i]);  // change top to i
    }
```

That said,

- In `push()`, youre doing

  ```
  scanf("%d",& stack[top]);
  top++;
  printf("%d",stack[top]);
  ```

  which is incrementing `top` before printing the *scanned* value. You don't want to increment `top` before printing.
- in your `push` function, the index `top` is unbound, wheras the actual array is bound (10 elements). You should at least put a check on `top` value (`<10` or alike) to make sure the index is within bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here:

- When inserting, you increment `top` before printing the top value, so it always prints 1 element *after the top*.
- When printing after inserting, you print `stack[top]` instead of `stack[i]`.
- In `display`, you have a stray semicolon right after the `for`, resulting in an empty loop body.

Comment: I am unable to find any mistake in dispaly function
can You Please elaborate last mistake

Comment: @AyushBhagoliwal In `display`, you have `for(i=0;i<=top;i++);`.  The semicolon at the end means the loop body is empty and does nothing.  The block statement after it then only runs once at the end of the loop.